# kendoui angular grid selection event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to handle a selection event from a KendoUI Grid in AngularJS.

I have got my code working as per below. However it feels like a really nasty way of having to get the data for the selected row. Especially using _data. Is there a better way of doing this? Have I got the wrong approach?

```
<div kendo-grid k-data-source="recipes" k-selectable="true" k-sortable="true" k-pageable="{'refresh': true, 'pageSizes': true}"
            k-columns='[{field: "name", title: "Name", filterable: false, sortable: true},
            {field: "style", title: "Style", filterable: true, sortable: true}]' k-on-change="onSelection(kendoEvent)">
</div>

$scope.onSelection = function(e) {
  console.log(e.sender._data[0].id);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

please try the following:

```js
    $scope.onSelection = function(kendoEvent) {
        var grid = kendoEvent.sender;
        var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        console.log(selectedData.id);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was facing the same problem.Is there some place I am missing where such things are documented? I am starting off with angular-kendo and treeviews in particular, and am having to scour SO for tips.

Answer (score 5):

Joining the party rather late, there is a direct way to do it without reaching for the grid object:

on the markup:

```
k-on-change="onSelection(data)"
```

in the code:

```
$scope.onSelection = function(data) {
    // no need to reach the for the sender
}
```

note that you may still send `selected`, `dataItem`, `kendoEvent` or `columns` if needed.

consult [this link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#event-handlers) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Directive for two-way binding to selected row. Should be put on the same element 
as kendo-grid directive.

**Typescript version:**

```
interface KendoGridSelectedRowsScope extends ng.IScope {
        row: any[];
    }

// Directive is registered as gridSelectedRow
export function kendoGridSelectedRowsDirective(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            link($scope: KendoGridSelectedRowsScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery) {

                var unregister = $scope.$parent.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", (event, grid) => {
                    if (unregister)
                        unregister();

                    // Set selected rows on selection
                    grid.bind("change", function (e) {

                        var selectedRows = this.select();
                        var selectedDataItems = [];

                        for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                            var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
                            selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
                        }

                        if ($scope.row != selectedDataItems[0]) {

                            $scope.row = selectedDataItems[0];
                            $scope.$root.$$phase || $scope.$root.$digest();
                        }
                    });


                    // Reset selection on page change
                    grid.bind("dataBound", () => {
                        $scope.row = null;
                        $scope.$root.$$phase || $scope.$root.$digest();
                    });

                    $scope.$watch(
                        () => $scope.row,
                        (newValue, oldValue) => {
                            if (newValue !== undefined && newValue != oldValue) {
                                if (newValue == null)
                                    grid.clearSelection();
                                else {
                                    var index = grid.dataSource.indexOf(newValue);
                                    if (index >= 0)
                                        grid.select(grid.element.find("tr:eq(" + (index + 1) + ")"));
                                    else
                                        grid.clearSelection();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                });
            },
            scope: {
                row: "=gridSelectedRow"
            }
        };
    }
```

**Javascript version**

```
function kendoGridSelectedRowsDirective() {
        return {
            link: function ($scope, element) {
                var unregister = $scope.$parent.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function (event, grid) {
                    if (unregister)
                        unregister();
                    // Set selected rows on selection
                    grid.bind("change", function (e) {
                        var selectedRows = this.select();
                        var selectedDataItems = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                            var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
                            selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
                        }
                        if ($scope.row != selectedDataItems[0]) {
                            $scope.row = selectedDataItems[0];
                            $scope.$root.$$phase || $scope.$root.$digest();
                        }
                    });
                    // Reset selection on page change
                    grid.bind("dataBound", function () {
                        $scope.row = null;
                        $scope.$root.$$phase || $scope.$root.$digest();
                    });
                    $scope.$watch(function () { return $scope.row; }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                        if (newValue !== undefined && newValue != oldValue) {
                            if (newValue == null)
                                grid.clearSelection();
                            else {
                                var index = grid.dataSource.indexOf(newValue);
                                if (index >= 0)
                                    grid.select(grid.element.find("tr:eq(" + (index + 1) + ")"));
                                else
                                    grid.clearSelection();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            scope: {
                row: "=gridSelectedRow"
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick example of how to do this with an angular directive.

Note here that I'm getting the reference to the underlying kendo grid through the click event and the DOM handle.

```
    //this is a custom directive to bind a kendo grid's row selection to a model
    var lgSelectedRow = MainController.directive('lgSelectedRow', function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                //optional isolate scope aka one way binding
                rowData: "=?"
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                //binds the click event and the row data of the selected grid to our isolate scope
                element.bind("click", function(e) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        //get the grid from the click handler in the DOM
                        var grid = $(e.target).closest("div").parent().data("kendoGrid");
                        var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                        scope.rowData = selectedData;
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use like this, I was also getting undefined when I upgraded my application from angular 7 to 15. Now I get event details like this

```
public selectedRowChangeAction(event:any): void { 
console.log(event.selectedRows[0].dataItem.Id);  }
```

event has selected Row at its 0 index and you can have dataItem as first object and then you can have all object details whatever you have for example Id, Name,Product details whatever you want to select, Something like you can see in picture
[image]